# get value of model property in a partialLayout from _Layout page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have _PartialLayout page as follows

**_PartialLayout.cshtml**

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.listGroups)
{
    string idvalue = item.ID.ToString();

    switch (idvalue)
    {
        case "1":
            <div class="gp-sub1">
                <p class="hidden" id="gplineid">@item.ID</p>
                <h4><a id="gpline" href='#' class="gp1 open" data-staion="GP_LINE">@item.GroupName</a></h4>
            </div>
            break;
    }
    ...
}
```

This is _Layout Page

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
    <body class="ss">

    @Html.Partial("_PartialLayout")

</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {    
            $("#gpline").click(function () {
            alert($('#gplineid').val());
        });

    });

</script>
```

In partilview layout once `gpline` click I'm trying to get `gplineid` as above, but this not alert any result :(

Comment: The element with `id="gpline"` is a link which does not have a value! And what do you mean _get  gplineid_? Are you wanting the value of `@item.ID`?

Comment: yes I want to get `@item.ID`

Comment: Then as I have told you before - add `data-id="@item.ID"` to the link, and then get it using `alert $(this).data('id'));`

Answer (score 0):

Actually I able to get the value with the help of @Stephen like follows

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.listGroups)
{
    string idvalue = item.ID.ToString();

    switch (idvalue)
    {
        case "1":
            <div class="gp-sub1">
                <p class="hidden" id="gplineid" data-groupid="@item.ID">@item.ID</p>
                <h4><a id="gpline" href='#' class="gp1 open" data-staion="GP_LINE">@item.GroupName</a></h4>
            </div>
            break;
    }
    ...
}
```

and then in _Layout page

```
    $("#gpline").click(function () {
        alert($(this).closest('.gp-sub1').find("#gplineid").attr("data-groupid"))
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
$("#gplineid").html();
```

or

```
$("#gplineid").text();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
  $("#gpline").live("click",function () {
            alert($('#gplineid').val());
        });
```